# Why do I get large bevels on a curve with such a small bevel object?

Tags: nurbs-surface

I am bevelling a simple circle with another simple circle and as you can see from the screen shot below I have to make the bevel circle incredibly small and I still end up with a very large cross section. I don't understand why the cross section on the bevelled curve isn't the same size a[image]s the bevel curve.

[image]

Comment: Is the scale applied to both curves? (`Ctrl`+`A`)

Comment: When resizing the bevel shape are you in edit mode or object mode?

Comment: Ok, Ctrl-A and selecting rotation and scale worked. I'm not sure why though. Thanks for all the comments. I'll go investigate ctrl-A now...

Answer (score 7):

You will have to :

- apply the scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- select all point of the curve and reset the radius back to 1 :

[image]

Note : to avoid applying the scale just set the radius to  1/scale

Answer (score 4):

Once you've selected a bevel object, the `bevel_depth` and `bevel_resolution` parameter doesn't affect the bevel. Rescale the bevel object in Object or Edit mode, and you will see a change in the final geometry that the Curve uses.

[image]
and
[image]